# Does $T \frac{d}{dT} (\frac{L}{T})=C_p(B) - C_p(A)$ hold, where L(T) is the latent heat of phase transition $A\rightarrow B$?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, phase-transition

In Garrod's Statistical Mechanics and Thermodynamics, Exercise 6.15[image: Exercise 6.15]

contains the claim that $T \frac{d}{dT} (\frac{L}{T})=C_p(B) - C_p(A)$.

But it seems to me that this is false, for the derivative is not the partial one where $p$ is fixed.

Is the claim in the problem correct? How can I see this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start out with the following fundamental equations for the two phases:
$$dH_A=C_{pA}dT+\left[V_A-T\left(\frac{\partial V_A}{\partial T}\right)_P\right]dP$$
$$dH_B=C_{pB}dT+\left[V_B-T\left(\frac{\partial V_B}{\partial T}\right)_P\right]dP$$
So, along the equilibrium line, $$\frac{dL}{dT}=\frac{d(H_B-H_A)}{dT}=(C_{pB}-C_{pA})+\left[(V_B-V_A)-T\left(\frac{\partial (V_B-V_A)}{\partial T}\right)_P\right]\left[\frac{dP}{dT}\right]_{equal}$$where $\left[\frac{dP}{dT}\right]_{equal}$ is given by the Clapeyron equation:
$$\left[\frac{dP}{dT}\right]_{equal}=\frac{L}{T(V_B-V_A)}$$

I'm stuck at this point, because the desired relationship does not seem to be consistent with this.

Comment: By deriving it another way I confirmed your answer, which was in doubt since it differed from what was in the question. Also the questioner seems to be wondering about the logic concerning how a total derivative becomes expressed in terms of partial derivatives. But I'm happy to delete my answer since you think it is superfluous.